# This in prototype function vs this in object literal function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to coding javascript plugin and i have in the last half year or so build about 2 plugins of my own, basically gallery plugins for my own personal use. now i usually use the following pattern in an IFFE.

```
$.Mypluginname = function() {
    this.anotherfunction(); // works !! 
}

$.mypluginname.prototype.anotherfunction(){
     // this points to $.Mypluginname awesome!!!
}

$.mypluginname.prototype.anotherfunction(){
    // this points to $.Mypluginname awesome!!!
}
```

But recently i have found a better JS plugin pattern, It looks like so,

```
$.Mypluginname = function() {

}

$.mypluginname.prototype = {

   anotherfunction : function(){
     // this points to $.Mypluginname awesome!!!  ... but how ? 
   }

   mypluginname : anotherfunction(){
    // this points to $.Mypluginname awesome!!!  ... but how ? 
   }

}
```

See how `this` still points to the main function, My question really is how ?

how is the this inside the below function:

```
$.Mypluginname = function() {
          this.anotherfunction(); // works !! ... can you answer this quinten.
    }
```

?

Can anybody explain ?

**EDIT** :: There are 12 answers in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work). none of which answer my question , which was not "how does prototype work" in the first place. reading that thread will certainly enhance my knowledge of JS prototype , but i don't see how it would explain how `this` works in the below design pattern.

```
$.mypluginname.prototype = {

       anotherfunction : function(){
         // this points to $.Mypluginname awesome!!!  ... but how ? 
       }

       mypluginname : anotherfunction(){
        // this points to $.Mypluginname awesome!!!  ... but how ? 
       }

    }
```

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: Half the code in your question is not valid Javascript. Can you post actual code?

Comment: `this` should *not* point to `$.Mypluginname` but to the respective instance you've called you method on.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi edited , i think it should make sense how .

Comment: Why the downvote ? i have edited the question to make sense !

Comment: I seriously fail to understand why this question was downvoted. I mean i have followed all the guidelines of SO, edited my question multiple times, answered. and i still get a downvote .

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi , i guess mistakes happen right ? when you post a question the right away and that why they have the `edit` button !

Comment: @Alexander, erm, yes, they do. There are still syntax problems left after your edits though. (If you were inquiring about the downvotes, none of them are mine.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The lack of `,` in the object literals ! ?

Comment: @Alexander, indeed, and also the `$.mypluginname.prototype.anotherfunction() {}` constructs.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik not to mention the case issues between your constructor and where you are assigning the prototype

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks ! i guess being specific helps everybody , as does sometimes overlooking minor details. but TY again for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks* like you are asking how

```
$.mypluginname.prototype.anotherfunction = function() {
 // this points to $.Mypluginname awesome!!!
}
```

works the same as

```
$.mypluginname.prototype = {
   anotherfunction : function(){
     // this points to $.Mypluginname awesome!!!  ... but how ? 
   }
}
```

and the answer is that they are functionally the same; (*one is replacing a key, one is replacing the whole prototype, but*) **in both cases** you are setting `anotherFunction` on the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` depends on how you **call** a function, not how or where you define it. All the different variations of code you have in the question are about the definition of the function, not the calling of it, so they don't make any difference.

Comment: i am sure your answer makes sense , but i am a JS newbie relatively , can you explain your answer , using the context i have provided . Thank would be more helpful ! TY.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik — As the answer says, none of the context you have provided is relevant to the value of `this`, so no, I can't.

Comment: i have commented out a peice of of specially for you `this.anotherfunction(); // works !! ... can you answer this quinten.` , check it out and tell me if it still lacks context.

Answer (score 0):

this is always a reference to its Object. What you are creating is a constructor function. Javascript is a language which does inheritance with prototypes (prototypal inheritance). So once you have called your constructor function with the new operator like this:

```
var someObj = new myConstrFunction(param);
```

it will return you an Object with your variables and functions.

```
console.log(someObj)
//basicly returns something like this (simplyfied) 
//{anotherFunction:function(){},someVal:"",someOtherval:true};
```

these functions and variables can reference to their objects by using "this" **in most cases**.

Comment: Except that there are several ways to call the functions defined on the prototype such that within those functions `this` will *not* be `someObj`.

Comment: valid point please give an example :)

Comment: `someObj.anotherFunction.call(someOtherObject)`